# Are commas allowed in the cookie value. Unclear specs

Tags: http, cookies, standards, specifications, rfc

From the [specs](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6265.txt):

```
cookie-value      = *cookie-octet / ( DQUOTE *cookie-octet DQUOTE )  cookie-octet      = %x21 / %x23-2B / %x2D-3A / %x3C-5B / %x5D-7E
                       ; US-ASCII characters excluding CTLs,
                       ; whitespace DQUOTE, comma, semicolon,
                       ; and backslash
```

Can you please help me interpret this? I am not sure if they mean the cookie value can contain comma or the other way around (can't contain comma).

This is important plz.

Comment: This is not the spec. See <https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc6265.html> instead.

Comment: @Julian Reschke  Thanks but the link you provided is a replication of the RFC doc. which I pointed. And your link does not provide an answer to my question.

Comment: No, previously you linked to an 20 year old spec.

Comment: Corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cookie-pair       = cookie-name "=" cookie-value
cookie-name       = token
cookie-value      = *cookie-octet / ( DQUOTE *cookie-octet DQUOTE )
cookie-octet      = %x21 / %x23-2B / %x2D-3A / %x3C-5B / %x5D-7E
                      ; US-ASCII characters excluding CTLs,
                      ; whitespace DQUOTE, comma, semicolon,
                      ; and backslash
```

So, according to the ABNF, the value can not contain a comma.